# ¿Cómo uso WHERE con fechas? SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

La pregunta seguramente puede sonar muy noob. Pero bueno, resulta que quiero ejecutar un simple where con fechas. He intentado de todo (hasta cambiar la columna de tipo DATE a tipo TEXT) y sigo sin tener resultados.

```
 Cursor curs = admin.selectWhere(DBScheme.Tabla_Asignaciones,new String[]{
            DBScheme.Columna_IdMateria,
            DBScheme.Columna_Descripcion,
            DBScheme.Columna_Fecha_Creacion,
            DBScheme.Columna_Fecha_Inicio,
            DBScheme.Columna_Fecha_Expiracion,
            DBScheme.Columna_Entregado},
            DBScheme.Columna_Fecha_Expiracion + "=?",
            new String[]{tiempo.getFecha(dia)});
```

La parte del **tiempo.getFecha(dia)**, es una función que devuelve la fecha (con el formato yyyy-MM-dd) pasándole como parámetro el día de la semana (Lunes, Viernes, Domingo...)

Me devuelve algo así: **2017-12-25** por ejemplo. Por cierto, aunque yo lo escriba directamente ("2017-12-25") sigue sin funcionar... me devuelve 0 filas.

**Actualizacion**

Las funciones que uso para ejecutar consultas:

```
  public Cursor selectLog(String query){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor selectWhere(String table,String[]columns, String whereCols, String[]whereArgs){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(table,columns,whereCols,whereArgs,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Con la sugerencia última que me dieron, por cierto, el primer código que mostre de esta pregunta, quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
Cursor curs = admin.selectLog("SELECT * FROM " + DBScheme.Tabla_Asignaciones +
    " WHERE " + DBScheme.Columna_Fecha_Expiracion + "='" + tiempo.getFecha(dia) + "'");
```

Comment: Porque no intentas ejecutar la consulta utilizando SQL como en cualquier otro gesto de base de datos?, si no sabes como comenta para poder ayudarte

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer en MySQL y funciona correctamente: https://imgur.com/a/bf2hC @AarónZúñiga

Comment: Cual es el formato de la fecha de la BD.

Comment: @David, es YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez lo puedas solucionar de esta manera:
**Actualizo la respuesta:**

```
public Cursor selectWhere(String fecha){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select * from Tabla_Asignaciones where fecha = '" + fecha + "';";
        //ejecutas la consulta
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //Al terminar cierras la BD
        db.close();
        return cur; 
    }
```

Después recorres el cursor para obtener los datos:

```
//Aqui puedes cambiar el parametro segun tus necesidades
Cursor cur = selectWhere('2017-12-15') 
if(cur.moveToFirst()){
   do {
        String nombre = cur.getString(0);
        String fecha = cur.getString(1);
       //Aqui puedes guaradar la informacion en un objecto, etc
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
```

Comenta si te ha servido!

Comment: De la forma que sugieres igualmente no me anda... es raro...

Comment: Hay algún error en la aplicación? Podrías agregar mas detalles a la pregunta como el código de tu base de datos y donde ejecutas la consulta

Comment: Voy a dejar la funcion que uso para hacer las consultas

Comment: @TwoDent ya esta actualizada la respuesta